# Problem animating matplotlib pcolor plot with polar projection using object

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to create a plotting object that produces an animated matplotlib pcolor plot with a polar projection. Currently the object can either create a set of polar plots or try to create an animation of those plots.

When creating the set of polar plots (but not the animation) the object works as planned.

The animation portion of the object is based on this [example](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/animation/basic_example.html), which works on my system. Unfortunately the animation as implemented in my object is not working.  There is a figure and an MP4 file produced for the animation but both the figure and the too-short animation both show just some mis-shaped axes.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to capture this figure series in an animation when embedded in an object?

I am using python 3.7, matplotlib 3.03 on a windows 10 machine

The code for the object and the code to run its instantiation are given below.

```
class Polar_smudge(object):
 # object for creating polar contour plots

 def __init__(self,  azimuth_grid, range_grid):
   import numpy as np

   self.azimuth_grid  = np.deg2rad(azimuth_grid)
   self.range_grid    = range_grid      
   self.fig =  None 
   self.ax =  None 
   self.images = []
 #------------------------------------------------------------------   
 def add_data(self, value_grid):
   import numpy as np

   self.value_grid = value_grid
   self.value_grid[self.value_grid<=0] = np.nan


 #------------------------------------------------------------------   
 def add_figure(self, value_grid):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # make and set-up figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
    ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.set_rlim([0,10])
    # make plot
    cax = ax.pcolor(self.azimuth_grid, self.range_grid, value_grid,  cmap=plt.cm.viridis_r)
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()


 #------------------------------------------------------------------   
 def start_figure(self):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # make and set-up figure
    if self.fig is  None :
      self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(111, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
      self.ax[0].set_theta_zero_location("N")
      self.ax[0].set_theta_direction(-1)


 def update_figure(self, value_grid):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # make figure and add to image list
    self.images.append((self.ax[0].pcolor(self.azimuth_grid, self.range_grid, value_grid,  cmap=plt.cm.viridis_r),))


 def end_figure(self):
    import matplotlib.animation as animation

    # animate the figure list
    im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(self.fig, self.images, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,blit=True)
    im_ani.save('smudge.mp4')

#============This runs the object ====================================  
import numpy as np

azimuth_bins  = np.linspace(0, 360, 360)
range_bins     = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)

# make plotting azim range grids
range_grid, azimuth_grid = np.meshgrid(range_bins, azimuth_bins)

# this works but isnt what I want
good_smudge = Polar_smudge(azimuth_grid,range_grid)  
for ix in range(3):
    val_grid = np.random.randn(360,30)
    good_smudge.add_figure(val_grid)

# this doesnt work
bad_smudge = Polar_smudge(azimuth_grid,range_grid)  
bad_smudge.start_figure()  
for ix in range(3):
    val_grid = np.random.randn(360,30)
    bad_smudge.update_figure(val_grid)
bad_smudge.end_figure()
```

In response to the comment from Earnest, I did some further refinement and it appears that the problem is not linked to being embedded in an object, and also that increasing the number of frames (to eg. 30) does not solve the problem.  The code snippet below provides a more concise demonstration of the problem (but lacks the correctly produced figure output option).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

azimuth_bins  = np.linspace(0, 360, 60)
range_bins     = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)
images = []
# make plotting azim range grids
range_grid, azimuth_grid = np.meshgrid(range_bins, azimuth_bins)


fig,ax = plt.subplots(111, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax[0].set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax[0].set_theta_direction(-1)

for ix in range(30):
    val_grid = np.random.randn(60,30)
    images.append((ax[0].pcolor(azimuth_grid, range_grid, val_grid,  cmap=plt.cm.viridis_r),))


# animate the figure list
im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,blit=False)

im_ani.save('smudge2.mp4')
```

Comment: For me even the example from the matplotlib docs does not produce any reasonable output when only 3 frames are used. I could imagine that to be expected due to the video encoding.